# Importing an svn branch into git

Tags: svn, git

I am new to git, and have a subversion repository that I want to be able to import into a git repository occasionally (for deployment). So I want to perform most of the updates using svn but wanted to see what's the best way to push it to git (just the default/master branch).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you only want to import the master/trunk branch of your svn repository, but I would like to mention **[svn2git](http://rubyforge.org/projects/svn2git/)** in order to import your svn into a git repository.

It is better than  `git svn clone` because if you have this code in svn:

```
  trunk
    ...
  branches
    1.x
    2.x
  tags
    1.0.0
    1.0.1
    1.0.2
    1.1.0
    2.0.0
```

**`git-svn`** will go through the commit history to build a new git repo.
It **will import all branches and tags as remote svn branches, whereas what you really want is git-native local branches and git tag objects**.
So after importing this project, you would get:

```
  $ git branch
  * master
  $ git branch -a
  * master
    1.x
    2.x
    tags/1.0.0
    tags/1.0.1
    tags/1.0.2
    tags/1.1.0
    tags/2.0.0
    trunk
  $ git tag -l
  [ empty ]
```

After svn2git is done with your project, you'll get this instead:

```
  $ git branch
  * master
    1.x
    2.x
  $ git tag -l
    1.0.0
    1.0.1
    1.0.2
    1.1.0
    2.0.0
```

Finally, it makes sure the HEAD of master is the same as the current trunk of the svn repo.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just work in git on your workstation too? That would be the most straightforward.

- `git svn clone` will grab your SVN repository and import the revisions into a new git repo.
- If you need to push to a remote git repository for deployment, then `git remote add` will add it for you.
- If you need to push back to the SVN repository then `git svn dcommit`

Answer (score 1):

in a nutshell:

```
mkdir my_blog_tmp
cd my_blog_tmp
git-svn init http://code.yoursite.net/my_blog/trunk/ --no-metadata
git config svn.authorsfile ~/Desktop/users.txt
git-svn fetch
```

and congrats for joining us gits! [Here](http://www.gnome.org/~newren/eg/git-for-svn-users.html) is a great cheat sheet for (ex)svn users.